# Sql server filter by different column based on parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have stored procedure that select query from multiple tables 
my stored example:

```
create procedure MyProc(@param bit)
as
select *
from Customers 
where [PhoneNumber]='some data'
```

I want change condition column `if @param=0 write (where [PhoneNumber]='some data')` or `if @param=1 (where [PhoneNumberSEC]='some data')` without duplicate `select` statement by `if else` condition.

Please, can I change filtering column-based on parameter sent to stored procedure without duplicate my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
create procedure MyProc(@param bit)
as
select *
from Customers 
where (@param = 0 AND [PhoneNumber]='some data') OR
(@param = 1 AND [PhoneNumberSEC]='some data')
```